# Why do we read Megillat Ruth on Shabbat but not Megillat Esther?

Tags: shabbat, purim, shavuos

Megillat Esther is not read when Purim falls on Shabbat, as we are concerned that one may carry the scroll outside. However, Megillat Ruth is read when Shavuot falls on Shabbat. Why doesn’t the same concern apply to reading Megillat Ruth on Shabbat?

Comment: One cannot carry anything on shabbat without an eruv, including megillat ruth

Comment: https://www.jewishpress.com/judaism/judaism-101/why-do-we-read-the-megillah/2012/03/07/ https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/46624

Comment: The reason why Ruth can be read on Shabbos is because it is only a custom - not an obligation - and therefore there is no fear that one may carry the scroll of Ruth through a public domain to be brought to a scholar, in order to learn its laws - because it has no laws, it’s just a custom

Comment: @שלום and furthermore, even said custom is just that it be read at/for the synagogue. Purim has the obligation for every Tom, Dick, Harry, and Sally too to read it (or hear a reading).

Comment: Thank you, Joel K. I meant WITH an eruv. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you Shalom and Shalom. I appreciate your insights. I did mean WITH an eruv. Thank you again for answering the question for me. Gmar Chatimah Tovah.

Comment: How do you know that one cannot carry a megillat esther if there is an eruv?

Comment: I did not word the question well. Megillah Esther s not read on Shabbat lest one carry it outside of reshuth harabim (public area not enclosed by an eruv). I only wanted to know why that Halacha does not also apply to Megillat Ruth. Thanks, Joel K

Comment: Rabba made 3 decrees regarding actions that should not be done on shabbos and they are shofar on shabbos outside of the bes hamikdash, lulav, and megillah of shushan Purim (since the only day Purim would on shabbos would be shushan Purim) megilas rus was not part of this. Additionally it was a later custom that developed and not universally accepted

Comment: Thank you, Dude. Chag Sukkot Sameach!